# SQL subtract alias and create another

Tags: sql

i would like to subtract the "alias" i created called "SALES" & "GP" and create a new column call GP

```
 SELECT OEEL.invoicedt, UCASE(OEEL.whse) AS Whse, OEEL.orderno, OEEL.ordersuf,
        OEEL.custno, UCASE(OEEL.shipto) AS Shipto, UCASE(OEEL.slsrepin) AS Slsrepin, 
        UCASE(OEEL.slsrepout) AS Slsrepout, OEEL.returnfl, OEEL.netamt, OEEL.wodiscamt,
        OEEL.discamtoth, OEEL.qtyship, OEEL.commcost, ICSS.csunperstk,
        UCASE(ICSD.name) AS Name, UCASE(ICSD.region) AS Region,
        UCASE(OEEL.prodcat) AS Prodcat, UCASE(SASTA.descrip) AS Descrip,
        UCASE(OEEL.transtype) AS Transtype, UCASE(ARSS.user2) AS User2, 
        OEEL.transdt, ICSS.transdt AS "ICSS.Transdt", ICSD.transdt AS "ICSD.Transdt",
        SASTA.transdt AS "SASTA.Transdt", ARSS.transdt AS "ARSS.Transdt",
        { fn CURDATE() } AS CURDATE1, { fn CURTIME() } AS CURTIME2, 
        OEEL.lineno,
        CASE
            WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth)
            ELSE (-1*(OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth))
        END AS "SALES",
        CASE
            WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.qtyship*OEEL.commcost*NVL(ICSS.csunperstk,1))
            ELSE (-1*OEEL.qtyship*OEEL.commcost*NVL(ICSS.csunperstk,1))
        END AS "COST"
   FROM { oj 
            { oj
                { oj
                    { oj PUB.oeel OEEL
                         LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.icss ICSS
                              ON OEEL.cono = ICSS.cono
                             AND OEEL.shipprod = ICSS.prod
                             AND OEEL.icspecrecno = ICSS.icspecrecno
                    }
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.icsd ICSD
                          ON OEEL.cono = ICSD.cono AND OEEL.whse = ICSD.whse
                }
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.sasta SASTA
                      ON OEEL.cono = SASTA.cono AND OEEL.prodcat = SASTA.codeval
            }
             LEFT OUTER JOIN PUB.arss ARSS
                  ON OEEL.cono = ARSS.cono
                 AND OEEL.custno = ARSS.custno
                 AND OEEL.shipto = ARSS.shipto
        }
  WHERE (OEEL.cono = 1)
    AND (OEEL.invoicedt BETWEEN { d '2014-06-02' } AND { d '2014-06-03' })
    AND (SASTA.codeiden IN ('C', 'c'))
  ORDER BY OEEL.custno, OEEL.shipto, OEEL.prodcat
```

Comment: Column alias GP not found? or Do you mean COST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following at last column

```
(CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth) ELSE (-1*(OEEL.netamt-OEEL.wodiscamt-OEEL.discamtoth)) END) - (CASE WHEN OEEL.returnfl = '0' THEN (OEEL.qtyship*OEEL.commcost*NVL(ICSS.csunperstk,1)) ELSE (-1*OEEL.qtyship*OEEL.commcost*NVL(ICSS.csunperstk,1)) END) AS GP
```